# Set ip for socket PHP

Tags: php, sockets, ip, fsockopen

Im using the following function for socket :

```
if (function_exists('stream_context_create') && function_exists('stream_socket_client')) {
    $socket_options = array('socket' => array('bindto' => '192.0.2.1:0'));
    $socket_context = stream_context_create($socket_options);
    $socket = stream_socket_client('ssl://xmlapi.example.org:9090', $errno,
        $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $socket_context);
} else {
    $socket = @fsockopen( "ssl://xmlapi.example.org" , 9090 , $errno , $errstr , 30 );
}
```

But `IP` dont change, its still shows server `IP` but functions are exist and 1st case it executing.

Comment: Can you explain better please ?

Comment: I need to set `IP` of `socket` same as client `IP` i have found that function its create `socket` and connect well, but the `IP` is not changing. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you want to have a different ip. :$

Comment: I have a proxy and on some websites its changing lang. For example im going to `google.com` and my server is in Denmark so im getting `google.de` thats why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. Because the server is not the client.

Long answer: You can by creating custom packets in C, but you won't get two-way traffic. Because the server is not the client.